# Как с помощью рекурсии вычислить сумму ряда?

Tags: prolog, ряды, turbo-prolog

Ряд задан формулой k-го члена: 
а<sub>k</sub>=(2–а<sup>2</sup><sub>k-1</sub>)/2, a<sub>0</sub>=1

Как с помощью рекурсии на языке Turbo Prolog 2.0 вычислить сумму ряда?

k-й член задается в самом начале выполнения программы.

```
predicates
 sum(integer,real).
clauses
 sum(0,1):- !.
 sum(K,Sum):- NextK=K-1,
 sum(NextK,NextSum),
 Sum=(2-(NextK*NextK))/2 +NextSum.
goal 
 write("Vvedite K: "),readint(K),sum(K,Sum),write("Summa: ",Sum).
```

Comment: Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: добавь свой код в вопрос. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: как минимум у тебя формула не правильная: в формуле в квадрат возводится k-1 элемент, а у тебя ты в квадрат возводишь просто `k-1`

Comment: А как она должна выглядеть?

Comment: вместо NextK, в ней должно быть NextAk

Comment: Это я понял уже давно. Как это сделать в коде?

Comment: например добавить третий параметр в sum, в который будет текущий ak записываться

Comment: А можно, пожалуйста, пример кода? sum(A,K,Sum) это я знаю. А дальше?

Answer (score 1):

В коде в вопросе неверная формула. Вместо самих элементов последовательности в квадрат возводятся их индексы.

Для исправления нужно дополнительно вычислять сам элемент последовательности.

Например так:

```
sum(0,1,1):-!.
sum(K,Ak,Sum):-PrevK=K-1, /* получаем предыдущее значение K */
   sum(PrevK,PrevAk,PrevSum), /* получаем предыдущий элемент и предыдущую сумму */
   Ak=(2-(PrevAk*PrevAk))/2, /* получаем текущий элемент */
   Sum=PrevSum+Ak. /* добавляем его к сумме */
```

Comment: Ошибка 707 в `PrevK=K-1`

Comment: @Igor, а у меня работает. Ну и мой код в этой строке от твоего вообще не отличается

Comment: У меня TurboProlog 2.0

Comment: @Igor, у меня тоже. Скорее всего ты забыл поменять код вокруг.

Comment: Не забыл. Работает, но считает неправильно. Последняя версия моего кода работает, суммирует два предыдущих члена, а не все.

Comment: @Igor, я не понял что ты написал. Считает правильно, так как находится сумма ряда: от K=0, до K заданного пользователем. Как это связано с тем, что твоя версия кода суммирует два предыдущих члена, а не все, я не знаю.

Comment: Можно полную версию кода с goal?

Comment: @Igor, там все то же самое, единственное отличие в вызове Sum: `sum(K,Ak,Sum)` В принципе вместо Ak, можно `_` ставить

Answer (score 0):

```
predicates
    sum(integer,real).
clauses
    sum(0,1.00):- !.
    sum(K,Sum):- K1=K-1,
    sum(K1,Sum1),
    Sum=(2-(Sum1*Sum1))/2.
goal
    write("Vvedite K: "),readint(K),sum(K,Sum),write("Summa: ",Sum).
```

Comment: формула все еще неверная

Comment: Потому я и прошу помощи.